# How can I convert a select list to bar buttons?

Tags: css, web

How can I make the selector on the right work like the image on the left? [image: like in the **left**]

Comment: it's a picture i don't have the code

Comment: bootstrap [button groups](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups) may be what you look for.

Answer (score 2):

By styling the label tied to the checkbox instead, utilizing the `for` attribute and hiding the input field.

```css
input {
  display: none;
}
label {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  background: #eee;
  padding: .5em;
  margin: 0 .5em 0 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
input:checked + label {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<input id="one" type="checkbox" name="thing"><label for="one">one</label>

<input id="two" type="checkbox" name="thing"><label for="two">one</label>

<input id="three" type="checkbox" name="thing"><label for="three">one</label>
```